# Javascript code for calculator in separate file

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have this Javascript in a separate file:

```
function calcularPontos_a()
{
    var totala = 0
    var a1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a1").value)  || parseFloat("0")
    var a2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a2").value)  || parseFloat("0") 
    var a3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a3").value)  || parseFloat("0")
    var a4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a4").value)  || parseFloat("0")
    var a5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a5").value)  || parseFloat("0")
    var a6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a6").value)  || parseFloat("0")
    var a7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a7").value)  || parseFloat("0")
    var a8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a8").value)  || parseFloat("0")
    var a9 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a9").value)  || parseFloat("0")
    var a10 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a10").value)  || parseFloat("0")
    var a11 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a11").value)  || parseFloat("0")
    var a12 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a12").value)  || parseFloat("0")
    var a13 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a13").value)  || parseFloat("0")
    var a14 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a14").value)  || parseFloat("0")                                  
    var a15 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a15").value)  || parseFloat("0")
    var a16 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a16").value)  || parseFloat("0")
    totala = ((a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5+a6+a7+a8+a9+a10+a11+a12+a13+a14+a15+a16)/100)*9
    return totala.toFixed(2)

}
```

and call this function in this way on my html page:

```
<input type="submit" value="Calcular" id="btnCalcular" class="btn" onClick="calcularPontos_a();window.location.reload()">
```

This is working great on Firefox, but on IE, Chrome and Safari is not working! Any clue?

Comment: What's the point in reloading the page immediately after the function is done running?

Comment: Which errors appear in your console log?

Comment: Define "not working". What's in the console?

Comment: Hello @PetrČihula! The values are not showing after running Javascript!

Comment: @OtavioLipari you're reloading the page after the function returns, obviously you don't see the results then anymore. It's Firefox that appears to be behaving strangely, not Chrome and IE.

Comment: @fonZ, sorry..."Basic" Javascript...ok now? translation issues... thanks!

Comment: `parseFloat("0")`?! What's wrong with just plain `0`?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, thanks for your answer! I removed the reloading code and the result are shown, but not immediately...I have to reload the page manually

Comment: You really need to look into your console logs.

Comment: Have you heard of arrays?

Comment: @OtavioLipari What is reloading the page supposed to accomplish? If you want to output the value, just use javascript to write it to an element. Frankly, I'm surprised this works at all.

Comment: guys! @ic3b3rg post the solution...my code was a crap! thanks for all the inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly a simplification of your existing code but it might fix the issue.  Let me know if the problem persists.

```
function calcularPontos_a() {

  var i,totala = 0;
  for(i=1;i<17;i++) totala += parseFloat(document.getElementById("a" + i).value) || 0;
  return (totala * 9 / 100).toFixed(2);

}
```

Edit:

To answer your question in the comments, use this version:

```
function calcularPontos_a() {

  var i,totala = 0;
  for(i=1;i<17;i++) totala += parseFloat(document.getElementById("a" + i).value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("link-01").innerHTML = "PONTOS GRUPO A: " + (totala * 9 / 100).toFixed(2) + " PTS";

}
```

Use this button:

```
<button id="btnCalcular" class="btn" onClick="calcularPontos_a();">Calcular</button>
```

Comment: Great! It's working! What's the best way to show the result of this function on a HTML tag after a button click? I'm using 

`<li class="link-01">PONTOS GRUPO A: <script>document.write(calcularPontos_a()) </script> PTS </li>`Thanks @ic3b3rg!

Comment: Also, as others have already mentioned, you shouldn't be reloading the page or using a submit. Use the button I added to the answer, or something similar.